# Insert File preview into sharepoint custom callout control

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2013

I followed example here   http://blog.alexboev.com/2012/08/custom-callouts-in-sharepoint-2013.html to create callout control.

Now I'm trying to add Preview pane for documents(images, pptx, pdf etc..) in callout control. (similar to the OOTB functionality when user clicks  on ellipse in document library item or search result).
How can I achieve this in my own callout control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [SharePoint 2013 - Custom CallOut with File Preview](http://community.obilogic.co.uk/blogs/teamblog/archive/2014/01/23/sharepoint-2013-custom-callout-with-file-preview.aspx).

It provide a working code sample:

```
function getCallOutFilePreviewBodyContent(urlWOPIFrameSrc, pxWidth, pxHeight) {
    var callOutContenBodySection = '<div class="js-callout-bodySection">';
    callOutContenBodySection += '<div class="js-filePreview-containingElement">';
    callOutContenBodySection += '<div class="js-frame-wrapper" style="line-height: 0">';
    callOutContenBodySection += '<iframe style="width: ' + pxWidth + 'px; height: ' + pxHeight + 'px;" src="' + urlWOPIFrameSrc + '&amp;action=interactivepreview&amp;wdSmallView=1" frameborder="0"></iframe>';
    callOutContenBodySection += '</div></div></div>';
    return callOutContenBodySection;
}

function OpenItemFilePreviewCallOut(sender, strTitle, urlWopiFileUrl) {
    RemoveAllItemCallouts();
    var openNewWindow = true; //set this to false to open in current window
    var callOutContenBodySection = getCallOutFilePreviewBodyContent(urlWopiFileUrl, 379, 252);
    var c = CalloutManager.getFromLaunchPointIfExists(sender);
    if (c == null) {
        c = CalloutManager.createNewIfNecessary({
            ID: 'CalloutId_' + sender.id,
            launchPoint: sender,
            beakOrientation: 'leftRight',
            title: strTitle,
            content: callOutContenBodySection,
            contentWidth: 420
        });
        var customAction = new CalloutActionOptions();
        customAction.text = 'Open';
        customAction.onClickCallback = function (event, action) {
            if (openNewWindow) {
                window.open(urlItemUrl);
                RemoveItemCallout(sender);
            } else {
                window.location.href = urlItemUrl;
            }
        };
        var _newCustomAction = new CalloutAction(customAction);
        c.addAction(_newCustomAction);
    }
    c.open();
}
```

Usage:

```
<a id="CallOutExample" onclick="OpenItemFilePreviewCallOut(this, 'My Title','<WopiFileUrl>')" title="CallOut With File Preview" h ref="#">Call Out with File Preview</a>
```

Comment: The original article seems to be inaccessible right now, but it is still on [archive.org](https://web.archive.org/web/20171104203833/http://community.obilogic.co.uk/blogs/teamblog/archive/2014/01/23/sharepoint-2013-custom-callout-with-file-preview.aspx)